# Apache Commons CLI muliple argument value names in the -help option

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I use Apache Commons CLI for parsing command line arguments.

I am looking for a way to display multiple argument value names in the help.
Here is an example for one argument of the option "startimport":

```
Option startimport = OptionBuilder
                .withArgName("environment")
                .hasArg()
                .withDescription(
                        "Description")
                .create("startimport");
```

When I use -help it prints out:

```
-startimport <environment>                    Description
```

Thatfs fine. But what if I want to use two arguments?

```
Option startimport = OptionBuilder
                .withArgName("firstArg secondArg")
                .hasArgs(2)
                .withDescription("Description")
                .create("startimport ");
```

Parsing the two arguments is not the problem but I want the following output in the "-help":

```
startimport <firstArg> <secondArg>                    Description
```

But currently I would just get:

```
startimport <firstArg secondArg>                    Description
```

Is there a proper solution for that problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used a naughty way to solve this problem.

```
    OptionBuilder.hasArgs(3);
    OptionBuilder.withArgName("hostname> <community> <oid");
    OptionBuilder.withDescription("spans switch topology. Mutually exclusive with -s");
    Option my_a = OptionBuilder.create("a");
```

It appears correctly in the help now. Though I am not sure if this has consequences though.

Answer (score 26):

I found a way to solve this problem in a way that behaves correctly, and thought I'd share because this is one of the pages Google led me to while researching. This code was written using Commons CLI 1.2.

```
Option searchApp = OptionBuilder.withArgName("property> <value")
            .withValueSeparator(' ')
            .hasArgs(2)
            .withLongOpt("test")
            .withDescription("This is a test description.")
            .create("t");
```

The help message looks like:

```
-t,--test <property> <value>    This is a test description.
```

It can be used from the command line like this:

```
java -jar program.jar -t id 5
```

and a String[] of the arguments can be retrieved in code like this:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(searchApp);
PosixParser parser = new PosixParser();
CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);
String[] searchArgs = cmd.getOptionValues("t");
```

Then you can retrieve the values with `searchArgs[0]` and `searchArgs[1]`.